# Почему выводит пустой массив?

Tags: python-3.x, алгоритм

Простые делители числа 13195 - это 5, 7, 13 и 29.

Каков самый большой делитель числа 600851475143, являющийся простым числом?

```
from math import *
def isPrime_number (n):
    if n < 2:
        return False
    if n == 2:
        return True

    divider = 2
    limit = sqrt(n)

    while divider <= limit:
        if n % divider:
            return False
        divider += 1

    return True

simple_dividers = []

n = int(input('Enter a num: '))

for i in range (1,int(sqrt(n))):
    if n % i == 0 and isPrime_number(i):
        simple_dividers.append (i)
print (max(simple_dividers))
```

Comment: Какой смысл перебирать в divider чётные, кроме двойки? равно как и нечётные, оканчивающиеся на 5, кроме самой пятёрки?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На простоту нужно проверить само число.

Цикл по делителям ограничить диапазоном до корня из числа.
Если `i` является делителем, то `q=n//i` - тоже. 
Таким образом, мы находим и проверяем на простоту сразу пару делителей.
Например, для n=65 проверяем делители до 9. Нашли 5 - проверили его и 65/5=13

Причём выгодно **сначала** проверить делимость, потом уже простоту

```
def isPrime_number (n):
    if n < 2:
        return False
    if n == 2:
        return True
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return False
    divider = 3
    limit = sqrt(n)

    while divider <= limit:
        if n % divider == 0:
            return False
        divider += 2

    return True

def maxprime(n):
    if isPrime_number(n):
        return n
    md = 0
    for i in range (2, int(sqrt(n)) + 1):
        if n % i == 0 :
            q = n // i
            if isPrime_number (q):
                return q
            if isPrime_number (i):
                md = max(md, i)
    return md

print(maxprime(13))
print(maxprime(64))
print(maxprime(65))
print(maxprime(75))
```

Можно также при нахождении делителя сразу делить на него число n, уменьшая его таким образом.
72: нашли 2, делим на 2, пока можно, получаем 36, 18, 9 и т.д.

Comment: *Можно также при нахождении делителя сразу делить на него число n* Я бы даже сказал "нужно"... иначе как определять кратность простого делителя?

Comment: @Akina Я так понял, что здесь кратность не нужна

Comment: В задаче поиска наибольшего простого делителя делить на найденный делитель тоже надо. Ну хотя бы потому, что это резко уменьшает диапазон поиска и, соответственно, время работы.

Comment: @MontyPython *что такое q* частное от деления исходного числа `n` на `i`. Если `i<sqrt(n)` и `q=n/i` простое, то `q` является решением задачи.

Comment: @Monty Python Код в комментариях не читабелен. Отредактируйте свой вопрос, добавьте туда

Comment: @Monty Python А зачем вам собирать простые множители в список, если нужен только самый большой?

Comment: @MBo Чтобы потом из массива вывести print (max(simple_dividers))

Comment: Достаточно хранить только текущий максимум `max_div = max(i, max_div)`